# fontspec not allowing to specify italic font in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}[
FakeBold=2,
%SmallCapsFont=PlayfairDisplaySC-Black.otf,
%BoldFont=ModernMTStd-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
%BoldItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
]

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
 \maketitle
 Just testing if the sum operator works.
        \begin{align*}
            F(n)
                & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)\\
            f\ast g
                & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Error shown: [image]

But font is located in the same directory. [image]

But if I comment out the italic font, it works properly.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}[
FakeBold=2,
%SmallCapsFont=PlayfairDisplaySC-Black.otf,
%BoldFont=ModernMTStd-Bold.otf,
%ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
%BoldItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
]

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Just testing if the sum operator works.
        \begin{align*}
            F(n)
                & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)\\
            f\ast g
                & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: In which directory did you saved the font files? I have no problem with ModernMT in my systems font directory.

Comment: in the same directory, please check the second picture

Comment: `fontspec` will look in the system font folder for system fonts; if the font files are elsewhere, tell `fontspec` where with the `Path=` option (Path, singular). Note: it seems, all files for the font definition are assumed to be in that path. When using the name-template method, define `UprightFont=`, as well; this will become the "normal" font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fontspec` looks in the system font folder for system fonts (installed fonts)*.

Otherwise, tell `fontspec` which folder the uninstalled fonts are in by using the `Path=` option.

For example, the following uses `AvrileSerif-Bold.ttf` as the upright font, and `ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf` as the italic font, both font files are in the local folder, so therefore the `Path=` option is set to `Path=./,`:

[image: path option]

This is an exaggerated example. I do not recommend random mixing of fonts for actual typesetting.

Note that text mode fonts (upright in blue, italics in red) are independent of math mode fonts).
MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{AvrileSerif}[
FakeBold=2,
%SmallCapsFont=PlayfairDisplaySC-Black.otf,
%BoldFont=ModernMTStd-Bold.otf,
Path=./,
UprightFont=*-Bold.ttf,
UprightFeatures={Colour=blue},
ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
ItalicFeatures={Colour=red},
%BoldItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
]

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
 \maketitle
 Just testing if the \textit{sum operator} works.
        \begin{align*}
            F(n)
                & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)\\
            f\ast g
                & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

*On Windows, fonts installed as user are not visible; instead, install them as admin.

Comment: this is still giving me errors. i installed the fonts as admin and can use them in if I specify the main font as a otf file instead of by the name. a little weird

Comment: Filenames are cleaner to find; "human" names require interpretation and assumptions, and sometimes multiple fonts or multiple installs of (different versions) of the same font in different locations misleads the search algorithm. Also, update/refresh the font database as well (the method depends on what set up you are using).

Answer (score 0):

Using your example with `ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic,` *without* `.otf`extension *and* using some italic text with `\textit` I get:

```
SSJTRD+OldStandard-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
YIVKHN+ModernMT-ExtendedItalic-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      6  0
SNOFLJ+CMMI10                        Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes yes      8  0
WBSDKO+CMR10                         Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes yes      9  0
GQLKOX+CMEX10                        Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes yes     10  0
VJTWUB+CMMI7                         Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes yes     11  0
FNWRCQ+CMSY7                         Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes yes     12  0
IOSJMP+CMSY10                        Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes yes     13  0
```

If you want to use a `text` font for the `math` variables printed in italics, then use package `unicode-math` and a *math* font or define the default math font with the text italics font, which is in general not. a good idea.

Comment: I am using windows and monotype modern is not installed by default. If I specify the font with the OTF extension in both setmainfont and in ItalicFont, then it works. But for some weird reason, without the OTF extension, if I call it by the font name, the same does not work

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise define the font formatting inside the \setmainfont

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{AvrileSerif}[
FakeBold=2,ext=.otf,
%SmallCapsFont=PlayfairDisplaySC-Black,
%BoldFont=ModernMTStd-Bold,
Path=./,
UprightFont=*-Bold.ttf,
UprightFeatures={Colour=blue},
ItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
ItalicFeatures={Colour=red},
%BoldItalicFont=ModernMT-ExtendedItalic.otf,
]

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    Just testing if the \textit{sum operator} works.
    \begin{align*}
        F(n)
        & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)\\
        f\ast g
        & = \sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```